# How to disable LiveAddress via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, smartystreets

So while LiveAddress works great for US address we have to support international addresses as well.  I already have a country dropdown that's enabling LiveAddress only when the person chooses the US.  However I need to now "disable" LiveAddress anytime someone picks a country other than the US.

```
$(".chosen-select").on("change", function (e) {
    if (e.added.id == "USA") {
        showUSStates();
        $.LiveAddress("<My Key>");
    } else if (e.added.id == "CAN") {
        showCANProvinces();
        //Disable Live Address here?
    } else {
        //Disable Live Address here?
        $("label[for=State]").html("Province");
        $("#State").hide()
        $("#Province").show()
        $("#State").empty();
    }
});
```

Thanks!

**Solution:**

So it's not documented in their web pages but I read the [unminimized js file](http://d79i1fxsrar4t.cloudfront.net/jquery.liveaddress/2.4/jquery.liveaddress.js) and discovered that if you map the country field they library AUTOMATICALLY turns itself off once someone chooses a country other than US.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        showUSStates();
        $.LiveAddress({
            key: "<My Key>",
            addresses: [{ 
                id: 'billing', 
                street: '#Address1', 
                city: '#City', 
                state: '#State', 
                zipcode: '#PostalCode', 
                **country: '#Country'** }],
            autoVerify: false
        });
    });
```

Great feature, just unfortunate that the online documentation doesn't detail this NOR did the online chat team know of this feature.

Comment: what have you done so far...

Comment: Patel added the current jQuery "change" event listener function above.

Answer (score 1):

http://smartystreets.com/kb/liveaddress-api/plugin/advanced lists `autoVerify(...)`

```
autoVerify([newSetting]) ver 2.4.3+
Pass in a truthy value to turn on auto-verify, or a falsey value to turn it off. Don't pass in anything to simply return the current autoVerify setting.
```

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for?

**EDIT** `deactivate(...)` and `activate(...)` may be more useful for you?

Comment: So the autoVerify field is just specifying whether the address found on lookup is then verified with the USPS verification before submit automatically (once user pauses input).

The activate & deactivate specify if the particular set of address fields will be verified upon submit (default is yes).

So appreciate the effort but not quite what I was looking for.

Comment: Ah! I've never actually *used* LiveAddress, but good to know you solved it eventually!